# datatable server side pagination always show 1 page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm trying to implement server side pagination, filter with `jquery` `datatable`.

But It always create only one page at footer.

```
   public JsonResult UserList(int draw, int length, int start)
        {
            PaginattionModel<PointUserModel> paginationModel = new PaginattionModel<PointUserModel>()
            {
                draw = draw
            };
                int sortColumn = -1;
                string sortDirection = "asc";
                if (Request.Form["order[0][column]"] != null)
                {
                    sortColumn = int.Parse(Request.Form["order[0][column]"]);
                }
                if (Request.Form["order[0][dir]"] != null)
                {
                    sortDirection = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"];
                }
                int totalCount = 0;
                PointUserFilter pointUserFilter = new PointUserFilter()
                {
                    PageSize = length,
                    PageNumber = start,
                    SortDirection = sortDirection,
                    SortColumnNo = sortColumn
                };
                var getPointUsers = pointUserBl.GetPointUsers(pointUserFilter, out totalCount);
                paginationModel.data = getPointUsers;
                paginationModel.recordsFiltered = getPointUsers.Count();
                paginationModel.recordsTotal = totalCount;
                return Json(paginationModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

These are the values:

**draw=1, getPointUsers.Count()=5, totalCount =6**

I'm showing 5 records per page. so it should create 2 page. But it's not.

Comment: have a look at: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118363/GridView-with-Server-Side-Filtering-Sorting-and-Pa

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: So according to that article. `totalCount` will always be total no of rows in table. and `filteredCount` will be total no of records after applying filter.  which means `totalcount` is never going to change.
Am I right?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the line that is causing it to always be one page:

```
paginationModel.recordsFiltered = getPointUsers.Count();
```

You said that "getPointUsers.Count()" was "5".  So the recordsFiltered data item is the total number of records available with the current search filters applied.  So if your page size is 5 and your recordsFiltered is 5 then the DataTable thinks there is only one page available to display with the current filters.  I don't believe "recordsTotal" is used for paging calculations unless "recordsFiltered" is not present.

From your code it doesn't look like you are applying any filters so the error is likely in how you are computing the "totalCount" since the "recordsFiltered" value is based on how many data items are returned.  If you aren't going to apply any search filters on the DataTable then you could use "getPointUsers.Count()" for "recordsTotal" and "recordsFiltered" since they should never be different.